# Visual Studio 2017 : 'Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.VSSettings' threw an exception

Tags: visual-studio, c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS-project which has suddenly started throwing following error-- 
error  : The SDK resolver type "DotNetMSBuildSdkResolver" failed to load. The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.VSSettings' threw an exception.

None of the files in project would load.

Answer (score 0):

Users reported that solutions:
 1. Run as administrator or
 2. Repair by VS installer or
 3. Reduce version to 15.8